# Spring JdbcTemplate - how to prepend every query for achieving multitenancy?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

**Setup**

I have an app using Spring 4.3, JdbcTemplate, Hibernate 5 and MySQL 8. I have implemented multitenancy in hibernate per schema where i switch schemas using using hibernates multitenancy mechanism - `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` and doing there basically:

```
connection.createStatement().execute("USE " + databaseNamePrefix + tenantIdentifier);
```

and this works.

Now the reporting part of my app uses `JdbcTemplate` for querying the DB. 
And now i want to similarily before every query executed by JdbcTemplate issue this `USE tenantIdentifier` statement.

**Question**

How can i prepend some SQL or a statement to every query executed by JdbcTemplate?

**What i have tried**

I looked into JdbcTemplate and only thing i found is setting a `NativeJdbcExtractor`. I have tried the code below but it's not even loggin that he is going through this methods.

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("dataSource")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
  jdbcTemplate.setNativeJdbcExtractor(new SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor(){
     @Override
     public Connection getNativeConnection(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        LOGGER.info("getNativeConnection");
        System.out.println("aaa");
        return super.getNativeConnection(con);
     }

     @Override
     public Connection getNativeConnectionFromStatement(Statement stmt) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("aaa");
        LOGGER.info("getNativeConnectionFromStatement");
        return super.getNativeConnectionFromStatement(stmt);
     }

  });
  return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

Added feature request to Spring: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17342

EDIT: i looked at Spring 5 and they removed the JdbcExtractor thing so this is definetly the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be an easy way to do this with `JdbcTemplate` as some methods are very generic e.g. `execute(ConnectionCallback<T> action)` methods allows direct access to `java.sql.Connection` object.

It would be easier to have a separate `DataSource` bean for every tenant and resolve this with qualified auto-wiring in Spring.

Having per-tenant `java.sql.Connection` will allow to execute `USE tenantIdentifier` statement when new database connection is opened (some pool libraries support this out the box). As [MySQL USE statement docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html) this can be done once per session:

> The USE db_name statement tells MySQL to use the db_name database as the default (current) database for subsequent statements. The database remains the default until the end of the session or another USE statement is issued.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create jdbc template bean. Instead, you can use entity manager factory to create new instance of jdbc template, every time you need to execute a query.
This approach worked for me.

```
public class JdbcQueryTemplate {

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        EntityManagerFactoryInfo info = (EntityManagerFactoryInfo) emf;
        return new JdbcTemplate(info.getDataSource());
    }

    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getNamedJdbcTemplate(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        EntityManagerFactoryInfo info = (EntityManagerFactoryInfo) emf;
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(info.getDataSource());
    }
}
```

And then use the class for querying.

```
public class Test{

  @Autowired
  private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  public List<Entity> executeQuery() {
      return new JdbcQueryTemplate().getNamedJdbcTemplate(entityManagerFactory)
              .query("query", new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Entity.class));
  }
}
```

Comment: The solution works fine but it result to  Too many connections error.

Answer (score 0):

It's late, but this is my solution, maybe can help someone. Not very elegant, but it works very well.
I override `JdbcTemplate`, for spring 5:

```
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.*;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.*;

public class TenantJdbcTemplate extends JdbcTemplate {

    public TenantJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T execute(StatementCallback<T> action) throws DataAccessException {
        Assert.notNull(action, "Callback object must not be null");

        Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(obtainDataSource());
        boolean isTransactionalCon = isTransactionalConnection(con, getDataSource());
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            applyStatementSettings(stmt);
            Statement stmtToUse = stmt;
            if (!isTransactionalCon) {
                setSchema(stmtToUse);
            }
            T result = action.doInStatement(stmtToUse);
            handleWarnings(stmt);
            return result;
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            // Release Connection early, to avoid potential connection pool deadlock
            // in the case when the exception translator hasn't been initialized yet.
            String sql = getSql(action);
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(stmt);
            stmt = null;
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
            con = null;
            throw translateException("StatementCallback", sql, ex);
        }
        finally {
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(stmt);
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T execute(PreparedStatementCreator psc, PreparedStatementCallback<T> action)
                    throws DataAccessException {

        Assert.notNull(psc, "PreparedStatementCreator must not be null");
        Assert.notNull(action, "Callback object must not be null");
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            String sql = getSql(psc);
            logger.debug("Executing prepared SQL statement" + (sql != null ? " [" + sql + "]" : ""));
        }

        Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(obtainDataSource());
        boolean isTransactionalCon = isTransactionalConnection(con, getDataSource());

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            ps = psc.createPreparedStatement(con);
            applyStatementSettings(ps);
            if (!isTransactionalCon) {
                try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
                    setSchema(stmt);
                }
            }
            T result = action.doInPreparedStatement(ps);
            handleWarnings(ps);
            return result;
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            // Release Connection early, to avoid potential connection pool deadlock
            // in the case when the exception translator hasn't been initialized yet.
            if (psc instanceof ParameterDisposer) {
                ((ParameterDisposer) psc).cleanupParameters();
            }
            String sql = getSql(psc);
            psc = null;
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
            ps = null;
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
            con = null;
            throw translateException("PreparedStatementCallback", sql, ex);
        }
        finally {
            if (psc instanceof ParameterDisposer) {
                ((ParameterDisposer) psc).cleanupParameters();
            }
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(ps);
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T execute(CallableStatementCreator csc, CallableStatementCallback<T> action)
                    throws DataAccessException {

        Assert.notNull(csc, "CallableStatementCreator must not be null");
        Assert.notNull(action, "Callback object must not be null");
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            String sql = getSql(csc);
            logger.debug("Calling stored procedure" + (sql != null ? " [" + sql  + "]" : ""));
        }

        Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(obtainDataSource());
        boolean isTransactionalCon = isTransactionalConnection(con, getDataSource());
        CallableStatement cs = null;
        try {
            cs = csc.createCallableStatement(con);
            applyStatementSettings(cs);
            if (!isTransactionalCon) {
                try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
                    setSchema(stmt);
                }
            }
            T result = action.doInCallableStatement(cs);
            handleWarnings(cs);
            return result;
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            // Release Connection early, to avoid potential connection pool deadlock
            // in the case when the exception translator hasn't been initialized yet.
            if (csc instanceof ParameterDisposer) {
                ((ParameterDisposer) csc).cleanupParameters();
            }
            String sql = getSql(csc);
            csc = null;
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(cs);
            cs = null;
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
            con = null;
            throw translateException("CallableStatementCallback", sql, ex);
        }
        finally {
            if (csc instanceof ParameterDisposer) {
                ((ParameterDisposer) csc).cleanupParameters();
            }
            JdbcUtils.closeStatement(cs);
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
        }
    }

    private static void setSchema(Statement stmt) throws SQLException {
        stmt.execute("set search_path=\"" + TenantIdHolder.getTenantId() + "\";");
    }

    private static String getSql(Object sqlProvider) {
        if (sqlProvider instanceof SqlProvider) {
            return ((SqlProvider) sqlProvider).getSql();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static boolean isTransactionalConnection(Connection connection, DataSource dataSource) {
        ConnectionHolder conHolder = (ConnectionHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(dataSource);
        return conHolder != null && conHolder.getConnection() == connection;
    }

}
```